# rest / spread in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

guys can someone explain what `([head, ...[headTail, ...tailTail]])` in the input of  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015870/7232312) solution is doing? I can't comment and ask the writer due to low reputation!

he is writing a function that takes an array of arrays in input (based on where he calls it) but although I know few things about **rest** and **spread** in Java Script I cant figure this out!

Comment: FYI: this peace of code (`[head, ...[headTail, ...tailTail]]`) smells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lex82 correctly answered, this is a way to destructure an array. So, if you have

```
const [head, ...tail] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

You are saying assign the first element to `head`, and the remaining to `tail`. So, `head = 1` and `tail = [2,3,4]`.

In the answer that you cited, they are taking it one step further. They want the first (head), the second element (the head of the tail), and the remaining.

so what they want is `[headTail, ...tailTail] = tail`.

Now if we substitute the tail in the first statement, it becomes:

```
[head, ...[headTail, ...tailTail]] = [1,2,3,4]
```

where `head = 1`, `headTail = 2` and `tailTail = [3, 4]`

---

*You could simply do this instead:*

```
[head, headTail, ...tailTail] = [1,2,3,4]
```

It will give the same outcome

Comment: Thanks for your complete and clear answer! I guess it was the second opening bracket that confused me all along.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is "destructuring" a given array in the first element (head), the second element (headTail) and the rest (tailTail).

This simplier example should make it easier to understand:

```
let [head, ...tail] = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // head = 1, tail = [2, 3, 4]
```

This simple destructuring is just applied again to the tail in your example.