# Generate all possible combinations of strings from two arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, combinations

I currently have two arrays that look like this:

```
let suits = ['♣', '♦', '♥', '♠'];
let cards = ['A','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];
```

And I want to combine these to contain an array of 52 strings with all possible combinations of cards. E.g.:

```
['A♣', 'A♦', 'A♥', 'A♠', '2♣' ...]
```

I know I could write two nested "for loops" and concatonate them, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create every combination possible for the contents of two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936610/how-can-i-create-every-combination-possible-for-the-contents-of-two-arrays)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method.

```js
const suits = ['♣', '♦', '♥', '♠'];
const cards = ['A','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];
const ret = cards.flatMap((x) => suits.map((y) => `${x}${y}`));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that:

```js
const suits = ['♣','♦','♥','♠']
  ,   cards = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
  ;
const deck = cards.reduce((d,c)=>[...d,...suits.map(s=>s+c)],[])

console.log( deck )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or:

```js
const deck = Array.from({length:52},(_,i)=>suits[Math.floor(i/13)]+cards[i%13])
```