# Recursively combine and concatenate arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that I would like to map/recurse through and combine all the values into one array.

```
var array1 = ['steve', 'mike'];
var array2 = ['2020', '2019', '2018'];
```

The goal is to create an array of all the possible combinations:

```
['steve2020', 'steve2019', 'steve2018', 'mike2020', 'mike2019', 'mike2018']
```

I'm not sure if a map for for/next is appropriate or more efficient, but it's hurting my brain right now trying to decipher the recursion logic here. :)  Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap with map()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936610/how-can-i-create-every-combination-possible-for-the-contents-of-two-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `flatMap` and `map` to go over both arrays, combine them and flatten the outcome array.

```js
var array1 = ['steve', 'mike'];
var array2 = ['2020', '2019', '2018'];

const result = array1.flatMap((v) => array2.map((y) => `${v}${y}`));

console.log(result);
```