# Multiple Arrays to Single Flatterned Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Ive got 3 parent arrays that could sometimes be different lengths which are called **Options**
Each Option has values array which can also be different lengths
Example of this would be something like this

```
[
  {
    name: "Option 1",
    values: ["Blue","Red","Orange"]
  },
  {
    name: "Option 2",
    values: ["Small","Medium","Large"]
  },
  {
    name: "Option 3",
    values: ["Cotton","Satin"]
  }
]
```

The outcome should generate an array like this

```
[
  {
    title: "Blue/Small/Cotton",
    price: "10.00"
  },
  {
    title: "Blue/Small/Satin",
    price: "10.00"
  },
  {
    title: "Blue/Small/Cotton",
    price: "10.00"
  },
  {
    title: "Blue/Medium/Satin",
    price: "10.00"
  },
]
```

And So on.
Ive tried mapping through the options but knowing the size of the multiple arrays is what I couldnt figure out

**SOLUTION**
I managed to get a solution

```
product.options.reduce(
      (a, b) => a.flatMap((x) => b.values.map((y) => [...x, y])),
      [[]]
    );
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: I managed to Get something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936610/how-can-i-create-every-combination-possible-for-the-contents-of-two-arrays